# How can I speed up my optimization with Gekko?

Tags: arrays, performance, optimization, gekko

My program is optimizing the charging and decharging of a home battery to minimize the cost of electricity at the end of the year. The electricity usage of homes is measured each 15 minutes, so I have 96 measurement point in 1 day. I want to optimilize the charging and decharging of the battery for 2 days, so that day 1 takes the usage of day 2 into account. I wrote the following code and it works.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import math

# ------------------------ Import and read input data ------------------------

file = r'D:\Bedrijfseconomie\MP Thuisbatterijen\Spyder - Gekko\Data Sim 1.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Input', na_values='NaN')

dataRead = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Timestep','Verbruik woning (kWh)','Prijs afname (€/kWh)',
                                            'Capaciteit batterij (kW)','Capaciteit batterij (kWh)',
                                            'Rendement (%)','Verbruikersprofiel'])

timestep = dataRead['Timestep'].to_numpy()                                 
usage_home = dataRead['Verbruik woning (kWh)'].to_numpy()
price = dataRead['Prijs afname (€/kWh)'].to_numpy()
cap_batt_kW = dataRead['Capaciteit batterij (kW)'].iloc[0]              
cap_batt_kWh = dataRead['Capaciteit batterij (kWh)'].iloc[0]
efficiency = dataRead['Rendement (%)'].iloc[0]
usersprofile = dataRead['Verbruikersprofiel'].iloc[0]

# ---------------------------- Optimization model ----------------------------
# Initialise model
m = GEKKO()

# Global options
m.options.SOLVER = 1

# Constants
snelheid_laden = cap_batt_kW/4
T = len(timestep)

loss_charging = m.Const(value = (1-efficiency)/2) 
max_cap_batt = m.Const(value = cap_batt_kWh)
min_cap_batt = m.Const(value = 0)
max_charge = m.Const(value = snelheid_laden)                                    # max battery can charge in 15min
max_decharge = m.Const(value = -snelheid_laden)                                 # max battery can decharge in 15min

# Parameters
dummy = np.array(np.ones([T]))

# Variables
e_batt = m.Array(m.Var, (T), lb = min_cap_batt, ub = max_cap_batt)              # energy in battery
usage_net = m.Array(m.Var, (T))                                                 # usage home & charge/decharge battery
price_paid = m.Array(m.Var, (T))                                                 # price paid each 15min
charging = m.Array(m.Var, (T), lb = max_decharge, ub = max_charge)              # amount charge/decharge each 15min

# Intermediates
e_batt[0] = m.Intermediate(charging[0])
for t in range(T):
    e_batt[t] = m.Intermediate(m.sum([charging[i]*(1-loss_charging) for i in range(t)]))
usage_net = [m.Intermediate(usage_home[t] + charging[t]) for t in range(T)]
price_paid = [m.Intermediate(usage_net[t] * price[t] / 100) for t in range(T)]
total_price = m.Intermediate(m.sum([price_paid[t] for t in range(T)]))

# Equations (constraints)
m.Equation([min_cap_batt*dummy[t] <= e_batt[t] for t in range(T)])
m.Equation([max_cap_batt*dummy[t] >= e_batt[t] for t in range(T)])
m.Equation([max_charge*dummy[t] >= charging[t] for t in range(T)])
m.Equation([max_decharge*dummy[t] <= charging[t] for t in range(T)])
m.Equation([min_cap_batt*dummy[t] <= usage_net[t] for t in range(T)])
m.Equation([(-1*charging[t]) <= (1-loss_charging)*e_batt[t] for t in range(T)])

# Objective 
m.Minimize(total_price)

# Solve problem
m.solve()
```

My code is running and it works but despite that it gives a Solution time of 10 seconds, the total time for it to run is around 8 minutes. Does anyone know a way I can speed it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to speed up the Gekko code:

- Solve locally instead of on the public server. The option is `m=GEKKO(remote=False)`. The public server can slow down with many jobs.
- Use `sum()` instead of `m.sum()`. This can be faster for compiling the model. Otherwise, use `m.integral(x)` if you need the integral of `x`.
- Many of the equations are repeated at each time horizon step. Gekko is more efficient using a single equation definition with `IMODE=2` (for algebraic equation models) or `IMODE=6` (for differential / algebraic equation models) and then it creates the equations over the time horizon. You may need to use `m.vsum()` instead of `m.sum()`.

For additional diagnosis, try setting `m.options.DIAGLEVEL=1` to get a detailed timing report of how long it takes to compile the model and perform each function, 1st derivative, and 2nd derivative calculation. It also gives a detailed view of the solver versus model time during the solution phase.

**Update with Data File Testing**

Thanks for sending the data file. The run directory shows that the model file is 58,682 lines long. It takes a while to compile a model that size. Here is the solution from the files you sent:

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :          193
   Constants    :            5
   Variables    :        20641
   Intermediates:          578
   Connections  :        18721
   Equations    :        20259
   Residuals    :        19681
 
 Number of state variables:          20641
 Number of total equations: -        19873
 Number of slack variables: -         1152
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :           -384
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  3.37044E+01  5.00000E+00
    1  2.81987E+01  1.00000E-10
    2  2.81811E+01  5.22529E-12
    3  2.81811E+01  2.10942E-15
    4  2.81811E+01  2.10942E-15
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    10.5119999999879      sec
 Objective      :    28.1811214884047     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a version that uses `IMODE=6` instead. You define the variables and equations once and let Gekko handle the time discretization. It makes a much more efficient model because there is no unnecessary duplication of equations.

[image: Results]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import math

# ------------------------ Import and read input data ------------------------

file = r'Data Sim 1.xlsx'

data = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Input', na_values='NaN')

dataRead = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Timestep','Verbruik woning (kWh)','Prijs afname (€/kWh)',
                                            'Capaciteit batterij (kW)','Capaciteit batterij (kWh)',
                                            'Rendement (%)','Verbruikersprofiel'])

timestep = dataRead['Timestep'].to_numpy()                                 
usage_home = dataRead['Verbruik woning (kWh)'].to_numpy()
price = dataRead['Prijs afname (€/kWh)'].to_numpy()
cap_batt_kW = dataRead['Capaciteit batterij (kW)'].iloc[0]              
cap_batt_kWh = dataRead['Capaciteit batterij (kWh)'].iloc[0]
efficiency = dataRead['Rendement (%)'].iloc[0]
usersprofile = dataRead['Verbruikersprofiel'].iloc[0]

# ---------------------------- Optimization model ----------------------------
# Initialise model
m = GEKKO()
m.open_folder()

# Global options
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE  = 6

# Constants
snelheid_laden = cap_batt_kW/4
m.time = timestep

loss_charging = m.Const(value = (1-efficiency)/2) 
max_cap_batt = m.Const(value = cap_batt_kWh)
min_cap_batt = m.Const(value = 0)
max_charge = m.Const(value = snelheid_laden)                                    # max battery can charge in 15min
max_decharge = m.Const(value = -snelheid_laden)                                 # max battery can decharge in 15min

# Parameters
usage_home = m.Param(usage_home)
price = m.Param(price)

# Variables
e_batt = m.Var(value=0, lb = min_cap_batt, ub = max_cap_batt)  # energy in battery
price_paid = m.Var()                                              # price paid each 15min
charging = m.Var(lb = max_decharge, ub = max_charge)              # amount charge/decharge each 15min
usage_net = m.Var(lb=min_cap_batt)

# Equations
m.Equation(e_batt==m.integral(charging*(1-loss_charging)))
m.Equation(usage_net==usage_home + charging)
price_paid = m.Intermediate(usage_net * price / 100)
m.Equation(-charging <= (1-loss_charging)*e_batt)

# Objective 
m.Minimize(price_paid)

# Solve problem
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,e_batt.value,label='Battery Charge')
plt.plot(m.time,charging.value,label='Charging')
plt.plot(m.time,price_paid.value,label='Price')
plt.plot(m.time,usage_net.value,label='Net Usage')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

The model is only 31 lines long (see `gk0_model.apm`) and it solves much faster (a couple seconds total).

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            5
   Variables    :            8
   Intermediates:            1
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :            6
   Residuals    :            5
 
 Number of state variables:           1337
 Number of total equations: -          955
 Number of slack variables: -          191
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :            191
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Dynamic Control with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  3.46205E+01  3.00000E-01
    1  3.30649E+01  4.41141E-10
    2  3.12774E+01  1.98558E-11
    3  3.03148E+01  1.77636E-15
    4  2.96824E+01  3.99680E-15
    5  2.82700E+01  8.88178E-16
    6  2.82039E+01  1.77636E-15
    7  2.81334E+01  8.88178E-16
    8  2.81085E+01  1.33227E-15
    9  2.81039E+01  8.88178E-16
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
   10  2.81005E+01  8.88178E-16
   11  2.80999E+01  1.77636E-15
   12  2.80996E+01  8.88178E-16
   13  2.80996E+01  8.88178E-16
   14  2.80996E+01  8.88178E-16
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   0.527499999996508      sec
 Objective      :    28.0995878585948     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

There is no long compile time. Also, the solver time is reduced from 10 sec to 0.5 sec. The objective function is nearly the same (28.18 versus 28.10).

Here is a complete version without the data file dependency (in case the data file isn't available in the future).

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import math

# ------------------------ Import and read input data ------------------------
timestep = np.arange(1,193)                                 
usage_home = np.array([0.05,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.05,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.06,
                          0.05,0.07,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.06,0.07,0.07,
                          0.07,0.16,0.12,0.17,0.08,0.10,0.11,0.06,
                          0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.08,
                          0.08,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.05,0.07,
                          0.07,0.07,0.07,0.21,0.08,0.07,0.08,0.27,
                          0.12,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,
                          0.12,0.15,0.08,0.10,0.08,0.10,0.09,0.10,
                          0.09,0.08,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.21,0.12,0.10,0.10,
                          0.11,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.12,0.10,0.11,0.10,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.09,0.08,0.12,
                          0.10,0.11,0.11,0.10,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.06,
                          0.06,0.07,0.06,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,
                          0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.06,0.09,0.10,
                          0.10,0.22,0.08,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.08,0.08,
                          0.07,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.16,0.21,0.08,0.08,
                          0.09,0.09,0.10,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.12,0.24,
                          0.09,0.08,0.09,0.08,0.10,0.24,0.08,0.09,
                          0.09,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,
                          0.07,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.28,0.11,0.20,
                          0.10,0.09,0.28,0.10,0.15,0.09,0.10,0.18,
                          0.12,0.13,0.30,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.21,0.10,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.08])
price = np.array([209.40,209.40,209.40,209.40,193.00,193.00,193.00,
                    193.00,182.75,182.75,182.75,182.75,161.60,161.60,
                    161.60,161.60,154.25,154.25,154.25,154.25,150.70,
                    150.70,150.70,150.70,150.85,150.85,150.85,150.85,
                    150.00,150.00,150.00,150.00,153.25,153.25,153.25,
                    153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,151.35,151.35,
                    151.35,151.35,151.70,151.70,151.70,151.70,154.95,
                    154.95,154.95,154.95,150.20,150.20,150.20,150.20,
                    153.75,153.75,153.75,153.75,160.55,160.55,160.55,
                    160.55,179.90,179.90,179.90,179.90,202.00,202.00,
                    202.00,202.00,220.25,220.25,220.25,220.25,245.75,
                    245.75,245.75,245.75,222.90,222.90,222.90,222.90,
                    203.40,203.40,203.40,203.40,205.30,205.30,205.30,
                    205.30,192.80,192.80,192.80,192.80,177.00,177.00,
                    177.00,177.00,159.90,159.90,159.90,159.90,152.50,
                    152.50,152.50,152.50,143.95,143.95,143.95,143.95,
                    142.10,142.10,142.10,142.10,143.75,143.75,143.75,
                    143.75,170.80,170.80,170.80,170.80,210.35,210.35,
                    210.35,210.35,224.45,224.45,224.45,224.45,226.30,
                    226.30,226.30,226.30,227.85,227.85,227.85,227.85,
                    225.45,225.45,225.45,225.45,225.80,225.80,225.80,
                    225.80,224.50,224.50,224.50,224.50,220.30,220.30,
                    220.30,220.30,220.00,220.00,220.00,220.00,221.90,
                    221.90,221.90,221.90,230.25,230.25,230.25,230.25,
                    233.60,233.60,233.60,233.60,225.20,225.20,225.20,
                    225.20,179.85,179.85,179.85,179.85,171.85,171.85,
                    171.85,171.85,162.90,162.90,162.90,162.90,158.85,
                    158.85,158.85,158.85])
cap_batt_kW = 3.00             
cap_batt_kWh = 5.00
efficiency = 0.95
usersprofile = 1

# ---------------------------- Optimization model ----------------------------
# Initialise model
m = GEKKO()
#m.open_folder()

# Global options
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE  = 6

# Constants
snelheid_laden = cap_batt_kW/4
m.time = timestep

loss_charging = m.Const(value = (1-efficiency)/2) 
max_cap_batt = m.Const(value = cap_batt_kWh)
min_cap_batt = m.Const(value = 0)
max_charge = m.Const(value = snelheid_laden)                                    # max battery can charge in 15min
max_decharge = m.Const(value = -snelheid_laden)                                 # max battery can decharge in 15min

# Parameters
usage_home = m.Param(usage_home)
price = m.Param(price)

# Variables
e_batt = m.Var(value=0, lb = min_cap_batt, ub = max_cap_batt)  # energy in battery
price_paid = m.Var()                                              # price paid each 15min
charging = m.Var(lb = max_decharge, ub = max_charge)              # amount charge/decharge each 15min
usage_net = m.Var(lb=min_cap_batt)

# Equations
m.Equation(e_batt==m.integral(charging*(1-loss_charging)))
m.Equation(usage_net==usage_home + charging)
price_paid = m.Intermediate(usage_net * price / 100)
m.Equation(-charging <= (1-loss_charging)*e_batt)

# Objective 
m.Minimize(price_paid)

# Solve problem
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,e_batt.value,label='Battery Charge')
plt.plot(m.time,charging.value,label='Charging')
plt.plot(m.time,price_paid.value,label='Price')
plt.plot(m.time,usage_net.value,label='Net Usage')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've tried some of your options. Working with 'sum()' improves the solve speed a bit, but not that much. Solving it locally with 'm=GEKKO(remote=False)' even slows it down to 13 min instead of 8 min. I also tried 'IMODE=2' but this gives also the same solve time of 8min. Am I doing sometime wrong or should I try a completely different approach?

Comment: Could you post sample data so that the problem can be run? A simplified version of `Data Sim 1.xlsx` is needed for testing.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q_NLizMUMPE8IGewrNXfqz-lLM_boved/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=104786612700360067470&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: I forgot to put my link open for public, but it should be open now. Let me know if you cannot open it please.

Comment: @ArneDECLERCK - let me know if the edit helps. There is additional information on IMODE=6 on the Dynamic Optimization course website: https://apmonitor.com/do  I recommend the energy benchmark problems for additional examples: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks

Comment: the edit helps me a lot! Thank you very much for speeding up the optimization proces! I just ran some tests and this should do it.