# Python Gekko dynamic optimisation - set constraint at final timestep

Tags: python, gekko

I have been working on a similar problem as in [How can I speed up my optimization with Gekko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74800578/how-can-i-speed-up-my-optimization-with-gekko/77000552#77000552). The solution provided with IMODE= 6 has been very useful. So thank you. I have trying to expand the model in such way that the battery should have a final charge at the end of all timesteps. I have tried to implement this by creating an intermediate which is the sum of all charging. Yet, the model won't converge (on any random value).

```
total_charge = m.Intermediate(np.sum(charging))
m.Equation(total_charge == 5)
```

As well when trying to set minimum values the model fails to converge.

```
total_charge = m.Intermediate(np.sum(charging))
m.Equation(total_charge > 5)
```

Use of m.vsum gives the same error

```
total_charge = m.Intermediate(m.vsum(charging))
m.Equation(total_charge == 5)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Complete code below

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import math

# ------------------------ Import and read input data ------------------------
timestep = np.arange(1,193)                                 
usage_home = np.array([0.05,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.05,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.06,
                          0.05,0.07,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.06,0.07,0.07,
                          0.07,0.16,0.12,0.17,0.08,0.10,0.11,0.06,
                          0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.08,
                          0.08,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.05,0.07,
                          0.07,0.07,0.07,0.21,0.08,0.07,0.08,0.27,
                          0.12,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,
                          0.12,0.15,0.08,0.10,0.08,0.10,0.09,0.10,
                          0.09,0.08,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.21,0.12,0.10,0.10,
                          0.11,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.12,0.10,0.11,0.10,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.09,0.08,0.12,
                          0.10,0.11,0.11,0.10,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.06,
                          0.06,0.07,0.06,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,
                          0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.06,0.09,0.10,
                          0.10,0.22,0.08,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.08,0.08,
                          0.07,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.16,0.21,0.08,0.08,
                          0.09,0.09,0.10,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.12,0.24,
                          0.09,0.08,0.09,0.08,0.10,0.24,0.08,0.09,
                          0.09,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,
                          0.07,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.28,0.11,0.20,
                          0.10,0.09,0.28,0.10,0.15,0.09,0.10,0.18,
                          0.12,0.13,0.30,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.21,0.10,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.08])
price = np.array([209.40,209.40,209.40,209.40,193.00,193.00,193.00,
                    193.00,182.75,182.75,182.75,182.75,161.60,161.60,
                    161.60,161.60,154.25,154.25,154.25,154.25,150.70,
                    150.70,150.70,150.70,150.85,150.85,150.85,150.85,
                    150.00,150.00,150.00,150.00,153.25,153.25,153.25,
                    153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,151.35,151.35,
                    151.35,151.35,151.70,151.70,151.70,151.70,154.95,
                    154.95,154.95,154.95,150.20,150.20,150.20,150.20,
                    153.75,153.75,153.75,153.75,160.55,160.55,160.55,
                    160.55,179.90,179.90,179.90,179.90,202.00,202.00,
                    202.00,202.00,220.25,220.25,220.25,220.25,245.75,
                    245.75,245.75,245.75,222.90,222.90,222.90,222.90,
                    203.40,203.40,203.40,203.40,205.30,205.30,205.30,
                    205.30,192.80,192.80,192.80,192.80,177.00,177.00,
                    177.00,177.00,159.90,159.90,159.90,159.90,152.50,
                    152.50,152.50,152.50,143.95,143.95,143.95,143.95,
                    142.10,142.10,142.10,142.10,143.75,143.75,143.75,
                    143.75,170.80,170.80,170.80,170.80,210.35,210.35,
                    210.35,210.35,224.45,224.45,224.45,224.45,226.30,
                    226.30,226.30,226.30,227.85,227.85,227.85,227.85,
                    225.45,225.45,225.45,225.45,225.80,225.80,225.80,
                    225.80,224.50,224.50,224.50,224.50,220.30,220.30,
                    220.30,220.30,220.00,220.00,220.00,220.00,221.90,
                    221.90,221.90,221.90,230.25,230.25,230.25,230.25,
                    233.60,233.60,233.60,233.60,225.20,225.20,225.20,
                    225.20,179.85,179.85,179.85,179.85,171.85,171.85,
                    171.85,171.85,162.90,162.90,162.90,162.90,158.85,
                    158.85,158.85,158.85])
cap_batt_kW = 3.00             
cap_batt_kWh = 5.00
efficiency = 0.95
usersprofile = 1

# ---------------------------- Optimization model ----------------------------
# Initialise model
m = GEKKO()
#m.open_folder()

# Global options
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE  = 6

# Constants
snelheid_laden = cap_batt_kW/4
m.time = timestep

loss_charging = m.Const(value = (1-efficiency)/2) 
max_cap_batt = m.Const(value = cap_batt_kWh)
min_cap_batt = m.Const(value = 0)
max_charge = m.Const(value = snelheid_laden)                                    # max battery can charge in 15min
max_decharge = m.Const(value = -snelheid_laden)                                 # max battery can decharge in 15min

# Parameters
usage_home = m.Param(usage_home)
price = m.Param(price)

# Variables
e_batt = m.Var(value=0, lb = min_cap_batt, ub = max_cap_batt)  # energy in battery
price_paid = m.Var()                                              # price paid each 15min
charging = m.Var(lb = max_decharge, ub = max_charge)              # amount charge/decharge each 15min
usage_net = m.Var(lb=min_cap_batt)

# Equations
m.Equation(e_batt==m.integral(charging*(1-loss_charging)))
m.Equation(usage_net==usage_home + charging)
price_paid = m.Intermediate(usage_net * price / 100)
m.Equation(-charging <= (1-loss_charging)*e_batt)
total_charge = m.Intermediate(np.sum(charging))
m.Equation(total_charge == 5)                                     #set minimum amount of charge


# Objective 
m.Minimize(price_paid)

# Solve problem
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,e_batt.value,label='Battery Charge')
plt.plot(m.time,charging.value,label='Charging')
plt.plot(m.time,price_paid.value,label='Price')
plt.plot(m.time,usage_net.value,label='Net Usage')
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a final parameter to activate the constrain only at the end of the horizon. Otherwise, the equation `m.Equation(total_charge == 5)` is active at every point in the time horizon. The `m.integral()` function adds up the charging over the time horizon. Don't use `np.sum()` or `m.sum()` to add up the value over the time horizon. Those functions are a summation of a numpy array or list at each time point in the horizon. Here is an example of how to activate at only the last point in the time horizon:

```py
p = np.zeros_like(m.time); p[-1]=1
final = m.Param(p)

total_charge = m.integral(charging)
m.Equation(final*(total_charge-5) >= 0) #set minimum amount of charge
```

Use `final*(total_charge-5)>=0` instead of `final*total_charge>=5` to avoid `0>=5` and an infeasible equation at non-final points in the horizon. Here is the solution with the charging value final condition highlighted with a red dot.

[image: Final condition]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import math

# ------------------------ Import and read input data ------------------------
timestep = np.arange(1,193)                                 
usage_home = np.array([0.05,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.05,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.06,
                          0.05,0.07,0.07,0.09,0.07,0.06,0.07,0.07,
                          0.07,0.16,0.12,0.17,0.08,0.10,0.11,0.06,
                          0.06,0.06,0.06,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.08,
                          0.08,0.06,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.07,0.05,0.07,
                          0.07,0.07,0.07,0.21,0.08,0.07,0.08,0.27,
                          0.12,0.09,0.10,0.11,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.08,
                          0.12,0.15,0.08,0.10,0.08,0.10,0.09,0.10,
                          0.09,0.08,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.13,0.21,0.12,0.10,0.10,
                          0.11,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.12,0.10,0.11,0.10,
                          0.10,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.09,0.08,0.12,
                          0.10,0.11,0.11,0.10,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.06,
                          0.06,0.07,0.06,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,
                          0.05,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.06,0.09,0.10,
                          0.10,0.22,0.08,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.08,0.08,
                          0.07,0.08,0.07,0.07,0.16,0.21,0.08,0.08,
                          0.09,0.09,0.10,0.09,0.09,0.08,0.12,0.24,
                          0.09,0.08,0.09,0.08,0.10,0.24,0.08,0.09,
                          0.09,0.08,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.06,0.07,
                          0.07,0.05,0.05,0.06,0.05,0.28,0.11,0.20,
                          0.10,0.09,0.28,0.10,0.15,0.09,0.10,0.18,
                          0.12,0.13,0.30,0.10,0.11,0.10,0.10,0.11,
                          0.10,0.21,0.10,0.10,0.12,0.10,0.08])
price = np.array([209.40,209.40,209.40,209.40,193.00,193.00,193.00,
                    193.00,182.75,182.75,182.75,182.75,161.60,161.60,
                    161.60,161.60,154.25,154.25,154.25,154.25,150.70,
                    150.70,150.70,150.70,150.85,150.85,150.85,150.85,
                    150.00,150.00,150.00,150.00,153.25,153.25,153.25,
                    153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,153.25,151.35,151.35,
                    151.35,151.35,151.70,151.70,151.70,151.70,154.95,
                    154.95,154.95,154.95,150.20,150.20,150.20,150.20,
                    153.75,153.75,153.75,153.75,160.55,160.55,160.55,
                    160.55,179.90,179.90,179.90,179.90,202.00,202.00,
                    202.00,202.00,220.25,220.25,220.25,220.25,245.75,
                    245.75,245.75,245.75,222.90,222.90,222.90,222.90,
                    203.40,203.40,203.40,203.40,205.30,205.30,205.30,
                    205.30,192.80,192.80,192.80,192.80,177.00,177.00,
                    177.00,177.00,159.90,159.90,159.90,159.90,152.50,
                    152.50,152.50,152.50,143.95,143.95,143.95,143.95,
                    142.10,142.10,142.10,142.10,143.75,143.75,143.75,
                    143.75,170.80,170.80,170.80,170.80,210.35,210.35,
                    210.35,210.35,224.45,224.45,224.45,224.45,226.30,
                    226.30,226.30,226.30,227.85,227.85,227.85,227.85,
                    225.45,225.45,225.45,225.45,225.80,225.80,225.80,
                    225.80,224.50,224.50,224.50,224.50,220.30,220.30,
                    220.30,220.30,220.00,220.00,220.00,220.00,221.90,
                    221.90,221.90,221.90,230.25,230.25,230.25,230.25,
                    233.60,233.60,233.60,233.60,225.20,225.20,225.20,
                    225.20,179.85,179.85,179.85,179.85,171.85,171.85,
                    171.85,171.85,162.90,162.90,162.90,162.90,158.85,
                    158.85,158.85,158.85])
cap_batt_kW = 3.00             
cap_batt_kWh = 5.00
efficiency = 0.95
usersprofile = 1

# ---------------------------- Optimization model ----------------------------
# Initialise model
m = GEKKO()
#m.open_folder()

# Global options
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.IMODE  = 6

# Constants
snelheid_laden = cap_batt_kW/4
m.time = timestep

loss_charging = m.Const(value = (1-efficiency)/2) 
max_cap_batt = m.Const(value = cap_batt_kWh)
min_cap_batt = m.Const(value = 0)
max_charge = m.Const(value = snelheid_laden)  # max battery can charge in 15min
max_decharge = m.Const(value = -snelheid_laden) # max battery can decharge in 15min

# Parameters
usage_home = m.Param(usage_home)
price = m.Param(price)

# Variables
e_batt = m.Var(value=0, lb = min_cap_batt, ub = max_cap_batt)  # energy in battery
price_paid = m.Var()      # price paid each 15min
charging = m.Var(lb = max_decharge, ub = max_charge)  # amount charge/decharge each 15min
usage_net = m.Var(lb=min_cap_batt)

# Equations
m.Equation(e_batt==m.integral(charging*(1-loss_charging)))
m.Equation(usage_net==usage_home + charging)
price_paid = m.Intermediate(usage_net * price / 100)
m.Equation(-charging <= (1-loss_charging)*e_batt)

p = np.zeros_like(m.time); p[-1]=1
final = m.Param(p)

total_charge = m.integral(charging)
m.Equation(final*(total_charge-5) >= 0) #set minimum amount of charge

# Objective 
m.Minimize(price_paid)

# Solve problem
m.solve()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,e_batt.value,label='Battery Charge')
plt.plot(m.time,charging.value,label='Charging')
plt.plot(m.time,price_paid.value,label='Price')
plt.plot(m.time,usage_net.value,label='Net Usage')
plt.grid(); plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,total_charge.value,'r--',label='Total Charge')
plt.plot(m.time[-1],total_charge.value[-1],'ro',markersize=10)
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.grid(); plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

If you modify the problem and it has trouble finding a feasible solution then use a soft objective instead of the inequality constraint.

```py
m.Minimize(1000*final*(total_charge-5)**2)
```

This gives the same solution, but isn't infeasible if the final constrain can't be reached.